# Keycloak always returns 401 - Zuul api gateway for microservices

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, keycloak, netflix-zuul

I got a micro-service running behind an API - gateway(Zuul) which has secured endpoints with the use of Keycloak. Keycloak always returns **401** for the secured endpoints when accessed from a public client(eg: postman) even with a valid token.
I have done the same scenario without the use of the API gateway and works perfectly fine which isolates the issue to newly added api-gateway.(have configured clients, roles, and users in keycloak).

The gateway service client is confidential and
The API service client is public, in keycloak.

**All the services, including keycloak is running as docker containers.**
Below is the keycloak-spring boot configuration in the properties file.

```
keycloak :
  realm : admin-realm
  auth-server-url : http://keycloak:8080/auth
  ssl-required : external
  resource : gateway-service
  bearer-only : true
  credentials.secret : *********************
#  
  security-constraints[0] : 
    authRoles[0] : user
    securityCollections[0] : 
      patterns[0] : /api/*
```

**Solved**

The problem was with the mismatch between the issuer URL of the token (http://localhost:8080/auth/) and the keycloak configuration URL in the property file of the micro-service (http://keycloak:8080/auth).

This happens when I tested the microservice from outside the docker network. (From postman). It could be resolved after I added the hostname 'keycloak; to the host file of Windows,

- Open c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file as Administrator
- Add 127.0.0.1 keycloak

Then from the postman, we could access the keycloak endpoint as,

- http://keycloak:8080/auth......

Comment: What’s the full error?

Comment: Are you sure that Zuul forwards Authorization Header? Try to implement or find appropriate filter.

Comment: @masseyb The error i get is the typical 401 Unauthorized response.                
`code` {
    "timestamp": "2020-07-10T15:19:26.073+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/v1/admin"
}

Comment: @solveMe I will look into that.. Any other tips?

Comment: @solveMe Hi, the keycloak adapter is integrated to the zuul api gateway.

Comment: @SteffanDevotta Could you share your sample?